release conenction in JPA multitenancy connection provider
How to handle exception in releaseConenction(String tenantIdentifier, Connection connetcion) method which implements MultiTenantConnectionProvider. How do we ensure the connetcion will be closed if there is any exceptionin this method.
@Override
public void releaseConenction(String tenantIdentifier, Connection connetcion){
Statement st = connection.createStatement();
statement.execute(" ALTER SESSION SET CURRENT_SCHEMA="default");
connection.close()
}

}
I am seeing lots of connection close errors in logs.
